# WebSphere liberty web socket lost messages

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket, websphere-8

I'm playing with web sockets on WebSphere Liberty 16.0.0.3 and seeing something odd.  If I send a number of messages back to back using the `getAsyncRemote.sendText` method (say 4 in a row), there are times when 2 of the messages don't make it to the client application.  It feels like I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what the issue is.
Note, if I switch to the serialized approach, `getBasicRemote`, things work as expected and all messages are received.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, did some more debugging and finally found the error.
Very hidden was the following error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: write not allowed.  Most likely cause is that another Write or Close is in progress" which led to this: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/253442/is-the-was-liberty-websocket-implementation-not-th.html

For now, I'm just going to switch to the getBasicRemote approach and move on.

thanks!
-r